# Java - outofmemory error due to heap space

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, out-of-memory, heap-memory

Below are the logs::::

```
[WorkManager.springBatch : 30] ERROR [SwiftSystemMessageMDB] - Failed onMessage
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.hibernate.util.IdentityMap.get(IdentityMap.java:134) ~[hibernate-3.2.5.ga-im.jar:3.2.5.ga]
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.getCollectionEntry(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:389) ~[hibernate-3.2.5.ga-im.jar:3.2.5.ga]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Collections.processDereferencedCollection(Collections.java:48) ~[hibernate-3.2.5.ga-im.jar:3.2.5.ga]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Collections.processUnreachableCollection(Collections.java:39) ~[hibernate-3.2.5.ga-im.jar:3.2.5.ga]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushCollections(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:218) ~[hibernate-3.2.5.ga-im.jar:3.2.5.ga]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:77) ~[hibernate-3.2.5.ga-im.jar:3.2.5.ga]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:35) ~[hibernate-3.2.5.ga-im.jar:3.2.5.ga]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:969) ~[hibernate-3.2.5.ga-im.jar:3.2.5.ga]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1690) ~[hibernate-3.2.5.ga-im.jar:3.2.5.ga]
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-3.2.5.ga-im.jar:3.2.5.ga]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152) ~[hibernate-3.2.5.ga-im.jar:3.2.5.ga]
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:811) ~[hibernate-3.2.5.ga-im.jar:3.2.5.ga]
    at com.im.pcam.jdbc.contractualsettlement.CsCaBasisRuleHibernate.searchCSCABasisRuleFromUI(CsCaBasisRuleHibernate.java:90) ~[PCAM-EJB-Client-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Getting the above error logs
Below is the code
I am getting outofmemory error due to java heap space and don't have any idea what to do apart from increasing heap space..getting error when calling unique result although I have the query which is getting performed on primary key so
only one result will be there.

```java
 public CsCaBasisRule searchCSCABasisRuleFromUI(CsRulesSearchCriteria csRulesSearchCriteria) {
        CsCaBasisRule csCaBasisRule = null;
        Session session = InitSessionFactory.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(CsCaBasisRule.class);
        
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(csRulesSearchCriteria.getRuleBasisCd())) {
            crit.add(Expression.eq("csRuleSet.ruleSetId", csRulesSearchCriteria.getRuleSetId()));
        }
        if (csRulesSearchCriteria.getRuleId() != null) {
            crit.add(Expression.eq("ruleId", csRulesSearchCriteria.getRuleId()));
        }

        csCaBasisRule = (CsCaBasisRule) crit.uniqueResult();
        Object[] caFields = (Object[]) session
                .getNamedQuery("com.im.pcam.datatypes.contractualsettlement.CsCaBasisRule.selectCsCaBAsisRuleInfo")
                .setLong(0, csCaBasisRule.getRuleId()).uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Does your application use [Spring](https://spring.io/)?

Comment: yes..its using spring

Comment: So tag it with "spring" (and remove the "memory" tag)

Comment: done..can you please suggest here outofmemory comes after autoflushing...should I set flush mode to commit before query execution..Will it resolve the OOM exception?

Comment: you can use `jconsole` with every request to check for heap usage in requests you think causing memory leak

Comment: You get the exception on a single call of the method or during runtime ? Show the query and the entity (some circular references ?).

Comment: I think this info isnt enuogh to predict the issue. We need to debug the end to end.. Do you this is the only code you have?

Comment: You will need to analyse an Out of Memory issue with Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT),  which is going to point yobject(s) are causing this issue. You can check this as an example https://www.slideshare.net/RaulCastillo36/analyzing-a-memory-leak-problem. What is more, could you provide you heap size? gc.log?